# Bloom Filter for 208 million URLs

Tags: data-structures, probabilistic-algorithms, searching, big-data, bloom-filters

I need to create a bloom filter of 208 million URLs. What would be a good choice of bit vector size and number of hash functions? I tried a bit vector of size 1 GB and 4 hash functions, but it resulted in too many false positives while reading.

I have a huge web corpus containing web content of billions of URLs. I need to process the web content of URLs satisfying certain criteria: the URL should have appeared in web search results in the past 7 days at least 5 times. This is represented by a list of 208 million URLs. Joining the list directly with the web corpus is not feasible because of volume. So I am considering creation of a bloom filter out of the list and then using the bloom filter to prune out unnecessary URLs from the web corpus.

Comment: Hard to say as you haven't told us your goals etc, making this open ended. You best bet is to experiment.

Comment: @AryaBhata I have a huge web corpus containing web content of billions of URLs. I need to process the web content of URLs satisfying certain criteria (and this is represented by a list of 208 million URLs). Joining the list directly with the web corpus is not feasible because of volume. So I am considering creation of a bloom filter out of the list and then using the bloom filter to prune out unnecessary URLs from the web corpus.

Comment: Can you go deeper into the specifics? Like what is actually the criterion?

Comment: Criterion - the URL should have appeared in web search results in the past 7 days at least 5 times

Comment: Why don't you edit the question with whatever details you can provide? Perhaps give an example of how you intend to use the bloom filter.

Answer (score 6):

Using the formula from wikipedia for [Bloom filter false positives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter#Probability_of_false_positives), your proposal would have a false positive probability of about 0.00726%.  This assumes, among other things, that good hash functions are used.  The formula is:

$(1 - (1 - [1/m])^{kn})^k$

where $m$ is the number of bits in the filter, $k$ is the number of hash functions and $n$ is the number of entries in the filter.

Because items cannot be removed from a typical Bloom filter, if generation of the filter is too expensive, you might consider a counting Bloom filter to allow deletions.

(Although I have not read of it being used and do not know if it would be effective, one might use ORed signatures in each field instead of a set bit, where each signature has half or fewer of the bits set.  A possible match is found when ((entry_signature ^ test_signature) & test_signature) == 0 for each entry selected by a hash function.  If every signature has the same number of set bits, this would be like nesting a Bloom filter with a size equal to the signature size and the number of hash functions equal to the number of set bits.)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to try Siphash, what is 64-bit, cryptographically strong and extremely fast. It's keyed so you can use as many Siphash'es as you need, each providing 64 bits of variability